# The mac is invalid laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got involved into a new laravel project and tryed running the unit tests (that pass on my friend's project), and I got some fails. I looked into the laravel.log and saw multiple times this one:

> testing.ERROR: Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException: The MAC is invalid. in /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/erx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/BaseEncrypter.php:48

I tryed clearning the cache, and also running:
**php artisan key:generate**
but that didn't remove the problem. Is there anything else that I should try?

Comment: does your .env contain a valid `APP_KEY` ?

Comment: It does contain the key, how do I know if its valid

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Most probably you are trying to decrypt an old password (encrypted with another key) with a newly generated key. Probably restore the old key or reset the passwords.

Comment: php  7.0 - which passwords should i restore?

Comment: Has any of available answers answered your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your APP_KEY is probably not the same as local/remote. `Crypt::decryptString` then throws `MAC is invalid` error.

You should be able to get rid of this when you clean cache and cookies in the browser.

Also make sure keys are same.

Comment: The same with what? I have the key in .env and then at config/app.php they like looks like this: 'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

Comment: Can you generate new one? :)

Answer (score 0):

I may happen when you setup on dev machine new instance and open a browser with one APP_KEY and then regenerated it and trying to refresh page.

If it's the case: try to clear cookies in the browser. It will wipe session and new one will be created automatically using newly created key.

Answer (score 0):

If You Have An Data encrypted by `Crypt::encryptString($plain_text)`
and you format your computer
you must remove all hashed fields by this method from your database,
and then Hashed it again.
this what solved the problem for me,
I mean that the problem is that if you have an fields hashed by this method you must to delete it hash because it is different from computer to another

Answer (score 0):

I you have the two similar project locally, make sure they have the same APP_KEY